# Generics.SOP equivalent of everywhere/mkT (replacing products)

Tags: haskell

Are there examples of `generics-sop` that mimic SYB's `everywhere`/`mkT` behavior?

What I'm attempting to do, but not seeing how to do it successfully, is replace the `everywhere (mkT fixupSymbol)` in `main` with an equivalent `Generics.SOP` construction, i.e., use `Generics.SOP` to recurse into the product `(I (AbsAddr value))` and replace it with `(I (SymAddr label))`.

I could pass the symbol table to `gformatOperands`, polluting the `formatOperands` signature. That seems suboptimal.

Without `fixupSymbol`, the output would look like:

```
LD   B, 0x0000
LD   C, 0x1234
CALL 0x4567
```

Resolving addresses to symbolic labels:

```
gensop % stack ghci
Using main module: 1. Package `gensop' component exe:gensop with main-is file: <...>/Main.hs
gensop-0.1: configure (exe)
Configuring gensop-0.1...
gensop-0.1: initial-build-steps (exe)
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: gensop
GHCi, version 8.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( <...>/Main.hs, interpreted )
*Main> main
LD   B, 0x0000
LD   C, label1
CALL label2
*Main>
```

Cut down version of code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

module Main where

import Data.Data
import Data.Foldable (foldl)
import Data.Word (Word8, Word16)
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import Text.Printf
import Generics.SOP
import Generics.SOP.TH (deriveGeneric)
import Data.Generics.Aliases (mkT)
import Data.Generics.Schemes (everywhere)
import Data.HashMap.Strict (HashMap)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as H
import Data.Sequence (Seq, (|>))
import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq


type Z80addr = Word16
type Z80word = Word8

class Z80operand x where
  formatOperand :: x -> Text

main :: IO()
main = mapM_ T.putStrLn (foldl printIns Seq.empty $ everywhere (mkT fixupSymbol) insnSeq)
-- -------------------------------------------------^ Does this have a Generics.SOP equivalent?
  where
    printIns accum ins = accum |> T.concat ([mnemonic, gFormatOperands] <*> [ins])

    mnemonic (LD _)   = "LD   "
    mnemonic (CALL _) = "CALL "

    -- Generics.SOP: Fairly straightforward
    gFormatOperands {-elt-} =
      T.intercalate ", " . hcollapse . hcmap disOperandProxy (mapIK formatOperand) . from {-elt-}
      where
        disOperandProxy = Proxy :: Proxy Z80operand

    -- Translate an absolute address, generally hidden inside an instruction operand, into a symbolic address
    -- if present in the symbol table.
    fixupSymbol addr@(AbsAddr absAddr) = maybe addr SymAddr (absAddr `H.lookup` symtab)
    fixupSymbol other                  = other

    insnSeq :: Seq Z80instruction
    insnSeq = Seq.singleton (LD (Reg8Imm B 0x0))
              |> (LD (Reg8Indirect C (AbsAddr 0x1234)))
              |> (CALL (AbsAddr 0x4567))

    symtab :: HashMap Z80addr Text
    symtab = H.fromList [ (0x1234, "label1"), (0x4567, "label2")]

-- | Symbolic and absolute addresses. Absolute addresses can be translated into symbolic
-- labels.
data SymAbsAddr  = AbsAddr Z80addr | SymAddr Text
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Typeable, Data)

data Z80reg8 = A | B | C
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Typeable, Data)

-- | Cut down version of the Z80 instruction set
data Z80instruction = LD OperLD | CALL SymAbsAddr
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Typeable, Data)

-- | Load operands
data OperLD = Reg8Imm Z80reg8 Z80word | Reg8Indirect Z80reg8 SymAbsAddr
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Typeable, Data)

$(deriveGeneric ''SymAbsAddr)
$(deriveGeneric ''Z80reg8)
$(deriveGeneric ''Z80instruction)
$(deriveGeneric ''OperLD)

instance Z80operand Z80word where
  formatOperand word = T.pack $ printf "0x%04x" word

instance Z80operand SymAbsAddr where
  formatOperand (AbsAddr addr)  = T.pack $ printf "0x04x" addr
  formatOperand (SymAddr label) = label

instance Z80operand Z80reg8 where
  formatOperand A = "A"
  formatOperand B = "B"
  formatOperand C = "C"

instance Z80operand OperLD where
  formatOperand (Reg8Imm reg imm) = T.concat [formatOperand reg, ", ", formatOperand imm]
  formatOperand (Reg8Indirect reg addr) = T.concat [formatOperand reg, ", ", formatOperand addr]
```

The `gensop.cabal` file:

```
cabal-version:  >= 1.12
name:           gensop
version:        0.1
build-type:     Simple
author:         scooter-me-fecit
description:    No description.
license:        GPL-3

executable gensop
  default-language:     Haskell2010
  main-is: Main.hs
  build-depends:
    base,
    containers,
    bytestring,
    generics-sop,
    syb,
    text,
    unordered-containers

  default-extensions:
    OverloadedStrings,
    FlexibleInstances

  ghc-options: -Wall
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`generics-sop` provides no equivalents for recursive traversal schemes, such as these functions. If you need to deal with recursion in this library, the possible solution is to implement them. Although, defining such functions in SOP is related to some difficulties because it has a core generic view on data that doesn't distinguish recursive nodes from leaves. Recursion in this setting can be managed using closed type families (CTF) and some type class machinery. Closed type families allow you:

1. to implement the type-safe cast, which is needed for defining `mkT`,
2. to resolve the cases of recursive and non-recursive nodes—different
   instances of a type class—which otherwise overlap. (Another option
   is using pragmas for overlapping instances, a recent GHC feature;
   there is, however, some bias about overlapping instances in the
   Haskell community, so this solution is often considered as
   undesired.)

Using CTF for treating recursion has been described in an unpublished paper “Handling Recursion in Generic Programming Using Closed Type Families”, which uses the `generics-sop` library as a case study; it provides examples of defining recursive schemes in SOP.

SYB's `everywhere` supports families of mutually recursive datatypes. The following implementation allows to specify them as type-level lists.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, TypeFamilies, DataKinds,
             TypeApplications, ScopedTypeVariables, MultiParamTypeClasses,
             ConstraintKinds, FlexibleContexts, AllowAmbiguousTypes,
             FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances,
             UndecidableSuperClasses, TypeOperators, RankNTypes #-}

import Generics.SOP
import Generics.SOP.NS

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)
import Data.Type.Equality

type family Equal a x :: Bool where
  Equal a a = 'True
  Equal _ _ = 'False

class DecideEq (eq :: Bool) (a :: *) (b :: *) where
  decideEq :: Maybe (b :~: a)
instance a ~ b => DecideEq True a b where
  decideEq = Just Refl
instance DecideEq False a b where
  decideEq = Nothing

type ProofCast a b = DecideEq (Equal a b) a b

castEq :: forall a b. ProofCast a b => b -> Maybe a
castEq t = (\d -> castWith d t) <$> decideEq @(Equal a b)

type Transform a b = (Generic a, Generic b, ProofCast a b, ProofCast b a)

mkT :: Transform a b => (a -> a) -> b -> b
mkT f x = maybe x id $ castEq =<< f <$> castEq x

type family In (a :: *) (fam :: [*]) :: Bool where
    In a   ([a] ': fam) = 'True
    In [a] (a   ': fam) = 'True
    In a   (a   ': fam) = 'True
    In a   (_   ': fam) = In a fam
    In _   '[]          = 'False

class CaseEverywhere' (inFam :: Bool) (c :: * -> Constraint)
                      (fam :: [*]) (x :: *) (y :: *) where
  caseEverywhere' :: (forall b . c b => b -> b) -> I x -> I y

instance c x => CaseEverywhere' 'False c fam x x where
  caseEverywhere' f = I . f . unI
instance (c x, Everywhere x c fam) => CaseEverywhere' 'True c fam x x where
  caseEverywhere' f = I . f . everywhere @fam @c f . unI

class    CaseEverywhere' (In x fam) c fam x y => CaseEverywhere c fam x y
instance CaseEverywhere' (In x fam) c fam x y => CaseEverywhere c fam x y

caseEverywhere :: forall c fam x y . CaseEverywhere c fam x y
               => (forall b . c b => b -> b) -> I x -> I y
caseEverywhere = caseEverywhere' @(In x fam) @c @fam

type Everywhere a c fam =
  (Generic a, AllZip2 (CaseEverywhere c fam) (Code a) (Code a))

everywhere :: forall fam c a . Everywhere a c fam
           => (forall b . c b => b -> b) -> a -> a
everywhere f = to . everywhere_SOP . from
  where
    everywhere_SOP = trans_SOP (Proxy @(CaseEverywhere c fam)) $
                               caseEverywhere @c @fam f
```

*Usage* 
First, this can be examined with a small-scale example taken from the SYB paper. The implemented SOP-based `everywhere`, as compared to SYB's one, additionally takes two type arguments, passed through the explicit type application. The first one specifies a family of mutually recursive datatypes as a type list. The traversal will treat as recursive only those nodes whose types are specified in that list. The second argument is needed to provide a compiler with a ‘proof’ object for type-cast. The `T` synonym for the `Transform` constraint serves to allow its partial application.

```
data Company = C [Dept]
data Dept = D Name Manager [SubUnit]
data SubUnit = PU Employee | DU Dept
data Employee = E Person Salary
data Person = P Name Address
data Salary = S Float
type Manager = Employee
type Name = String
type Address = String

class    Transform a b => T a b
instance Transform a b => T a b

type CompanyF = '[Company, Dept, SubUnit, Employee]

increase :: Float -> Company -> Company
increase k = everywhere @CompanyF @(T Salary) (mkT (incS k))

incS :: Float -> Salary -> Salary
incS k (Sal s) = Sal (s * (1 + k))
```

The defined `everywhere` / `mkT` functions are ready for using in your code, but it misses some `Generic` instances. To apply `everywhere` to `insnSeq`, you need a `Generic (Seq Z80instruction)` instance. Yet you can't obtain it, because the `Data.Sequence` module doesn't export the internal representation of it. A possible fix is applying `fmap` to the sequence. So now you can write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

...

type Z80 = '[SymAbsAddr, Z80reg8, Z80instruction, OperLD]

main :: IO()
main = mapM_ T.putStrLn (foldl printIns Seq.empty $
  fmap (everywhere @Z80 @(T SymAbsAddr) (mkT fixupSymbol)) insnSeq)
```

You should provide the `Generic` instances for all types of nodes that this traverses, recursive and non-recursive. So next, this demands the `Generic` instances for `Word8`, `Word16`, and `Text`. While the `Generic Text` instance can be generated via `deriveGeneric`, the others can't, because of their special GHC representation. So you'll have to do it manually; this definition is straightforward:

```
$(deriveGeneric ''Text)

instance Generic Word8 where
  type Code Word8 = '[ '[Word8]]
  from x                        = SOP (Z (I x :* Nil))
  to   (SOP ((Z (I x :* Nil)))) = x

instance Generic Word16 where
  type Code Word16 = '[ '[Word16]]
  from x                        = SOP (Z (I x :* Nil))
  to   (SOP ((Z (I x :* Nil)))) = x
```

This code is boilerplate, but the newest GHC extension `DerivingVia` could nicely simplify this, reducing the second definition. Hopefully, this useful feature will be improved with possibilities for standalone deriving, so it will be possible to say instead:

```
deriving via Word8 instance Generic Word16
```

The whole code now works well, and `main` yields the expected result.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! That's an excellent answer, and an exceptional first contribution.

Comment: By the way: `Data.Sequence` intentionally avoids a `Generic` instance for two closely related reasons: 1. Sequences are supposed to be abstract so that users can easily switch between different sequence implementations to optimize their code. `Generic` reveals internal structure. 2. The functions and instances offered by `Data.Sequence` all respect `==` as long as they're only used with lawful instances of base classes. `Generic` does not, since trees are compared modulo balance.

Comment: Currently testing the code. Couple of notes so far: Control.Monad is redundant. Need to use ticked versions of True and False.

Comment: @dfeuer: It's clearly a feasible solution, but for more complex problems (Z80instruction has ~40 constructors, the Z80 type list has 10 elements), there's something that does not scale with GHC 8.6.3. Good test of I/O bandwidth and Mac OS's swapping algorithm. It works for this cut-down test case, but not for the actual code.

Comment: @dfeuer: I've never seen ghc use 40GB before.

Comment: The actual code is on Github, https://github.com/bscottm/emuwork. The disassembler's output is in src-emubase/Z80/DisasmOutput.hs.

Comment: @scootermefecit this ticket might be relevant https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5642